# Error message '405 method not allowed' when using php cURL with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

[image: error message]

This is the error message I receive when I try to run my code using jQuery. I don't think there's anything wrong with the jQuery package which would suggest it has something to do with my code.

Here is my code:

```
<?php


// ini_set('display errors', 'On');
// error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true) / 1000;

$url= 'http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeCountryInfoJSON?formatted=true' . $_REQUEST['countryName'] . '&username=jessed&style=full';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

$result=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$decode = json_decode($result,true);

$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "mission saved";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms ";
$output['data'] = $decode["geonames"];



header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

What can I try next?

Comment: The error message seems to point to the link between your front end and your own application rather than the link to the API you have above.

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen and how would I fix that?

Comment: As you haven't included the code, the only thing I can guess is that the web is using POST, but the route might be set to GET.  You could replace the code in your question with the form and the routes in your application.

Comment: Oh, perfect! Thank you!